# Meaning of the adverb 'differently' and its position

Tags: meaning, adverbs, syntactic-analysis

> Perceptual constancy refers to our ability to see things differently without having to reinterpret the object's properties.

Is *differently* referring to *we see* or *things*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adverb modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or other adverb.
The adverb *differently* is referring to the verb of the sentence you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

In your words, 'we differently see things'. 'Things' means 'the situation' as opposed to actual objects. Another way of phrasing it would be 'see things from a different perspective'.

If the author meant 'see different things', he would say 'see different things'! :)

Comment: @Elendi I think the 'see' really means 'see', not a 'perspective' ...... so, I replace the pronoun with the noun. sorry, for my carelessness.

Comment: Ah, sorry... I thought the quote was referring to some kind of abstract object (as in programming).

Answer (score -1):

It means that if we select a group of people, each one of them will see the same object/item in a different way. If you and I see a 8 oz glass with 4 oz of water, you may see it half-full and I half-empty.

Trivia: Apple's "think different" campaign should of read "think differently".

Comment: ...or, "think 'different'."

Comment: ...also, "should of" should have been "should have."